# delete files and directories in a directory according to the names of another directory

Tags: unix, piping

This may be a simple question: I accidentally copied a whole directory (call it A) to another directory (call it B), and now I want to delete all the "directory_A files" from directory B. I realize that maybe piping is a good idea, but I don't know how to do that... can I write in command line: (assume I am currently in directory B)

```
ls ~/path/to/directory_A | rm -f
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: the files remain in directoryB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Assuming current working directory is directory_B:

```
ls ~/path/to/directory_A | xargs rm
```

Comment: If the cwd is set to directoryB.  Correct?  You may want to add that.

Comment: Added. Thank for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd directoryA
ls directoryA > /tmp/t.lis
cd directoryB
while read fname
do
   rm "$fname"
done</tmp/t.lis
```

One approach to this.